# ssh-copy-id doesn't work with .pem files

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, ssh-keys

I am trying to copy an SSH public key on several EC2 instances.

Reading the `ssh-copy-id` man page, when you pass the key file, the program adds `.pub` extension if it missing.

AWS keys are generated are `.pem` format, and I can use this workaround:

```
ssh-keygen -y -f my-new-key.pem | ssh user@host \
-i already-on-remote-server-key.pem 'cat > ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'
```

But the doubt remains... *Is it possible to use `ssh-copy-id` with a `.pem` file or the only solution is to use a workaround?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `ssh-copy-id` together with `ssh-agent`. Load the `my-new-key.pem` file to your agent using `ssh-add ~/.ssh/my-new-key.pem` and then `ssh-copy-id` will copy it to the new instance.

Alternatively you can run a new `ssh-agent` for a better control of what's going to be copied:

```
~ $ ssh-agent bash -c "ssh-add ~/.ssh/my-new-key.pem; ssh-copy-id -i already-on-remote-server-key.pem user@host"
```

One unsolicited advice - you can reuse the EC2 keys across all AWS regions to reduce the number of keys you need to generate and maintain: **[Re-using EC2 Key Pair in multiple regions](https://aws.nz/best-practice/re-using-ec2-key-pair/)**.

Hope that helps :)